# sequelize findAndCountAll doesn't work when using required true on nested models

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am running into very strange issues, where sequelize doesn't seem to work the way I expect it to.
It gives me an error of
SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "productinstances"
when using required: true and trying to filter through data of any of the nested models. It works well whenever I query the Orders themselves.

```
 const orders = await Order.findAndCountAll({
    logging: console.log,
    distinct: true,
    limit,
    offset,
    col: `id`,
    where: where.orderWhere,
    include: [
      {
        model: ProductInstance,
        required: true,

        where: where.productInstanceWhere,
        include: [
          {
            model: Tracking,
            required: where.trackingRequired,
            where: where.trackingWhere,
          },
          {
            model: Product,
            required: where.productRequired,
            where: where.productWhere,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        model: User,
        required: true,
        where: where.userWhere,

        include: [
          {
            model: Delivery,
            required: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        model: Delivery,
        required: false,
      },
    ],
    order: [sortingObject],
  });

  res.json(orders);
});
```

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

const getOrderColumnFilters = (columnfilters) => {
  const orderFilter = [];
  const productInstanceFilter = [];
  const trackingFilter = [];
  const productFilter = [];
  const userFilter = [];

  if (columnfilters?.length > 2) {
    JSON.parse(columnfilters).forEach((filter) => {
      let query;
      if (filter.id === "id") {
        query = {
          [`$productinstances.id$`]: { [Op.eq]: Number(filter.value) },
        };
        productInstanceFilter.push(query);
      } else if (filter.id === "orderId") {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(filter.value)) {
          query = {
            [`$order.id$`]: { [Op.eq]: Number(filter.value) },
          };
          orderFilter.push(query);
        } else {
          query = {
            [`$user.username$`]: { [Op.iLike]: `${filter.value}%` },
          };
          userFilter.push(query);
        }
      } else if (filter.id.includes("order.")) {
        const filterId = filter.id.split(".").pop();
        if (filterId === "createdAt") {
          query = {
            [filterId]: {
              [Op.gte]: `${filter.value}%`,
            },
          };
        } else {
          query =
            filterId !== "fundsDeposited"
              ? {
                  [`$${filter.id}$`]: {
                    [Op.iLike]: `${filter.value}%`,
                  },
                }
              : { [`$${filter.id}$`]: { [Op.eq]: filter.value } };
        }
        orderFilter.push(query);
      } else if (filter.id === "color" || filter.id === "size") {
        query = {
          [`$productinstances.${filter.id}$`]: {
            [Op.iLike]: `${filter.value}%`,
          },
        };
        productInstanceFilter.push(query);
      } else if (filter.id === "ordered") {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        filter.value = filter.value === "true";
        query = {
          [`$productinstances.${filter.id}$`]: {
            [Op.is]: filter.value,
          },
        };
        productInstanceFilter.push(query);
      } else if (filter.id.includes("product.")) {
        const filterId = filter.id.split(".").pop();
        query =
          filterId !== "price"
            ? {
                [filterId]: {
                  [Op.iLike]: `${filter.value}%`,
                },
              }
            : { [filterId]: { [Op.eq]: filter.value } };
        productFilter.push(query);
      } else if (filter.id.includes("tracking.")) {
        // split filter id by . and get the last element
        const filterId = filter.id.split(".").pop();
        if (filterId === "estimatedArrival" || filterId === "sentDate") {
          query = {
            [filterId]: {
              [Op.gte]: `${filter.value}%`,
            },
          };
        } else {
          query = {
            [filterId]: {
              [Op.iLike]: `${filter.value}%`,
            },
          };
        }
        trackingFilter.push(query);
      }
    });
  }
  const orderWhere =
    orderFilter.length > 0 ? { [Op.or]: [...orderFilter] } : {};
  const productInstanceWhere =
    productInstanceFilter.length > 0
      ? { [Op.or]: [...productInstanceFilter] }
      : {};
  const trackingWhere =
    trackingFilter.length > 0 ? { [Op.or]: [...trackingFilter] } : {};
  const productWhere =
    productFilter.length > 0 ? { [Op.or]: [...productFilter] } : {};
  const userWhere = userFilter.length > 0 ? { [Op.or]: [...userFilter] } : {};

  const trackingRequired = trackingFilter.length > 0;
  const productRequired = productFilter.length > 0;

  return {
    orderWhere,
    productInstanceWhere,
    trackingWhere,
    productWhere,
    trackingRequired,
    productRequired,
    userWhere,
  };
};

module.exports = getOrderColumnFilters;
```

```
/// / ASSOSIATIONS //////////////////////////////

// USER has one DELIVERY
db.models.Delivery.hasOne(db.models.User, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.User.belongsTo(db.models.Delivery, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// Order has one ALTERNATIVE DELIVERY
db.models.Delivery.hasOne(db.models.Order, {
  foreignKey: { allowNull: true, name: "alternativeDeliveryId" },
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.Order.belongsTo(db.models.Delivery, {
  foreignKey: { allowNull: true, name: "alternativeDeliveryId" },
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// USER has many ORDERS
db.models.User.hasMany(db.models.Order, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.Order.belongsTo(db.models.User, {
  foreignKey: { allowNull: true },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

db.models.User.belongsTo(db.models.Delivery, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// ORDER has many PRODUCT INSTANCES
db.models.Order.hasMany(db.models.ProductInstance, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.ProductInstance.belongsTo(db.models.Order, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// PRODUCT has many PRODUCT INSTANCES
db.models.Product.hasMany(db.models.ProductInstance, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.ProductInstance.belongsTo(db.models.Product, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// TRACKING has many PRODUCT INSTANCES
db.models.Tracking.hasMany(db.models.ProductInstance, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.ProductInstance.belongsTo(db.models.Tracking, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});

// SCACCOUNT has many TRACKINGS

db.models.Scaccount.hasMany(db.models.Tracking, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
db.models.Tracking.belongsTo(db.models.Scaccount, {
  onDelete: "RESTRICT",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
```

I could use `required:false` on productInstances but it that case it returns incorrect count, which I need to be correct in order for my app to work properly. I can not figure out any solution. I tried to make it work with . notation option of eager loading but it completely brakes and seems to have a lot of bugs when it comes to nested querying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `subQuery: false` on main query?

That fixed it for me... https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7367#issuecomment-731459618